# Deleting an item from a listview with SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have a problem with deleting items from my database in listview. This is my code from my helper to delete data:

```
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + DB_TABLE + " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id +"'" + " AND "
                + COL2 + " = '" + name +"'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
```

It views the data with this code

```
 private void viewData() {
        Cursor cursor = bh.viewData();

        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                listItem.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItem);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

But the problem is I have no idea how to delete it from database

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                //It supposed to be deleted

            }
        });
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of problem are you having?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement it, I was trying for over an hour watching different youtube tutorials etc. and I just have no clue how to make it work

Comment: Try using [`Room`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room). It will make your life easier.

Comment: You are dealing with `id` as if it was a string: `... " WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id +"'" ...`. But (most likely) that column is an integer. Strings do not compare to integers, and you get no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short you are presneting a list that is a single string extracted from the database.

Your delete is expecting two values. The **id** and the **name** (the listed value).  Both values are not available from the single string that is listed.

If COL2 were UNIQUE (i.e. the same value would never be used) then you could easily just delete based upon this value but frequently names are not unique in which case it would be impossible to derive the id from the name. You would either have to use an ArrayList of objects (such an object containing both the id and the name) or have another array containing the id's that is in sync with the array of names.

I'd suggest using a CursorAdapter which :-

- caters for Cursors and most especially provides the **id** as the 4th parameter to the onItemClick (for other adapters it is the same as the 3rd parameter i.e. the position).

  - **NOTE** the **id** column MUST be named **_id**.
- Has all the rows in the Cursor used as the source available.
- Has the Cursor appropriately positioned when onItemClick (and also onItemLongClick) is called.

## Example

The following is an example based upon your code.

### DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COL1 = BaseColumns._ID; //<<<<<<<<<IMPORTANT uses the _id column
    public static final String COL2 = "mynamecolumn";


    public DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DB_TABLE +
                "(" +
                COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COL2 + " TEXT " +
                ")"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insert(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL2,name);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(DB_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public int delete(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // ID WILL BE UNIQUE so that's enough to IDentify a row
        return db.delete(DB_TABLE,COL1 + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    }

    public Cursor viewData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(DB_TABLE,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- The above should be similar to what you have **BUT** note the name **_id** *(obtained via the constant **BaseColumns._ID**)* for COL1.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper bh;
    Cursor csr;
    ListView lv;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = this.findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        bh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeDataIfNone(); //<<<<< Add some testing data
        manageListView(); //<<<<< Manage the LIstView
    }

    private void manageListView() {
        csr = bh.viewData();
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COL2},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    bh.delete(id); //<<<<< uses the 4th parameter 
                    manageListView(); //<<<<< refresh the ListView as the data has changed
                }
            });
        } else {
            adapter.swapCursor(csr);
        }
    }

    private void addSomeDataIfNone() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(bh.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE) > 0) return;
        bh.insert("Name 1");
        bh.insert("Name 2");
        bh.insert("Name 3");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        csr.close(); // Done with the Cursor so close it
        bh.close(); // Done with the Database as this is the Main Activity
        super.onDestroy();

    }
}
```

Note how this is also quite similar **BUT**

- uses the **SimpleCursorAdapter** as the source for the ListView. It iself uses a Cursor as the source for the data.
- does not create a new Adapter each time the data is viewed
- automatically refreshes the ListView when an item is clicked and thus deleted.
- uses the **id** to delete the clicked item as that is all that is needed to unqiuely **id**entify a row.

## Results

When first run :-

[image]

When clicking Name 2 :-

[image]